# How to distinguish entities in Dynamics CRM using the web API?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am using the request to `GET "/api/data/v9.0/EntityDefinitions"` to list all the entities that are present in Dynamics and get basic information regarding them ([EntityMetadata EntityType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/entitymetadata?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9)).
I know that some of the entities are **standard**, **custom**, **non-createable**, **non-updateable**, etc.
To check if an entity is a **custom** I can use a field named *IsCustom* from *EntityDefinition* and if it is *true* then the entity is **custom**. But for **non-createable** entities and others (I don't know how to call them properly) this approach is not applicable, because there is no such field.
For example, 'activitypointer' supports only GET operation ([activitypointer EntityType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/activitypointer?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9)). Records of this type cannot be created. But from the request above, I cannot get the correct information about that.

Can entities be distinguished?

P.S.: maybe I did something wrong and need to look elsewhere?